# Tensorflow: How to run many training minibatch steps?

Tags: session, optimization, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to speedup the training of my feedforward network (with layer sizes: 20-80-40-20-2.) My data set has about 100 000 data points. I am using the following code to train the model:

```
for ep in range(epochs):
    for i in range(0, N, mini_batch_sz):
        j = i + mini_batch_sz
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={vX:X[i:j], vY:Y[i:j]})
```

where epochs and mini_batch_sz is 10000 and 25 respectively. This loop will just do one mini-batch step per python loop. My GPU load during the training is just 15%. I am wondering whether it is possible to pass multiple mini-batch training data to tensorflow to reduce the interaction between python and underlying tensorflow engine?

Comment: The bottleneck  is usually not the interaction between python and underlying tensorflow engine. A few thing here you can try to speed up the code: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide

Comment: Thanks, i was aware of the mentioned page and tried out some of them, none has helped, unfortunately.  Another thing I noticed is that my training job runs on CPU (with 6 cores) much fast (2x faster) than on GPU that has over 2K cuda units. Also, my training dataset is just few MB size, everything is loaded and pre-processed into main memory.

Comment: In what you posted I don't really see anything wrong unless your data, `X`, and `Y` are in lists and not numpy arrays. So I suggest you add a timer and print out how long you're spending in the call to `sess.run` and how long you're spending outside of `sess.run`. You should be spending trivially small amounts of time outside of `sess.run` if you're not (and I suspect you aren't), figure out why not, the GPU will be idle for all of this time.

Answer (score 0):

`20-80-40-20-2` is not a particularly large set of matrix multiplies to saturate the GPU. Also, since you are feeding the data from `numpy` (or a list) during every training step, the copy from Python to C++ and CPU to GPU are all part of the critical path. Since you mention that your training data is only a few `MB` in size, you can consider placing the entire training data in the GPU memory as a `tf.constant`, do the slicing on GPU, and only pass `i` and `j` per training step.